# bootstrap 3 carousel abnormal: blank content appears when go "prev" before the 1st slider item, but working perfect as long as click "next"

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

Bootstrap 3 carousel abnormal without error message, 
blank content appears clicking prev slide before the 1st one, but act totally normal when click next slide.

[issue url](http://elf.solstice.sg/tateanzur/workgallery/)

1.click the right edge slider will go next and there would be no issue, looping successful.

2.click the left edge ( after reach before THE 1st slider item ) and you will see blank(BLACK) and carousel will not working  , but my chrome console not showing any useful info for debugging. :(

I just unable to locate the cause in this case, and dont know if it's a dup question.
  any similar problem / duplicate issue link found just comment below.

the init code i used looks quite normal

```
$("#myCarousel").carousel({
            interval: 15000,
            pause: true,
            cycle:true                
});
```

HTML carousel part (I'm using bootstrap 3 carousel as u can see even id names unchanged the same with its demo id name. I think i didn't do much change.)

```
<div class="bs-example">

  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Carousel indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators hidden">
     <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
     <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1" class=""></li>
      .............................
</ol>

<!-- Carousel items -->
<div class="carousel-inner">
  <div class="carousel-nav-right-btn hidden-sm hidden-xs"></div>
  <div class='item active' style="background-image:url(http://elf.solstice.sg/tateanzur/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/slider_bg4.png);background-size:cover;background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position:center;height:100%;">
    <div class="carousel-caption">
      <h3 style="padding-top:80px;">slider caption text</h3>
      ................................ 
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='item ' style="background-image:url(http://elf.solstice.sg/tateanzur/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/slider_bg5.png);background-size:cover;background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position:center;height:100%;">
    <div class="carousel-caption">
      <h3 style="padding-top:80px;">slider caption text</h3>
       .................................
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Carousel nav -->
<a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
</a>
<a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
</a>
</div>
</div>
```

a few questions in this case which looks wierd to me:

1.the carousel is working, and loop cycle at right direction work well but sure there is something wrong with the left direction

2.no error message comes out in chrome when it turns black in left direction. (i'm using chrome bowser,anyone find error message in other browsers)

Please forgive me didn't paste the full code here as I'm not sure which part of the full code has triggered this issue yet, (pasting full code also looks messy) once issue located,I will re EDIT the post with the short sample code as the cause of this issue.

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link 
to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value
to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, 
see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: I totally agree with pasting an essence code sample of the issue will do good and help reader in future, but sometimes debugger can not precisely locate the issue, such as carousel in demo page confirm no problem, but before locating the true cause, we are not able to grab the key problem code here (then including whole code might be messy),therefore, providing a temp live url might also be a complete environment for debugging sometimes you see in a lot of post ppl reqest the OP to paste more codes for debuging or guessing around which file has/hasn't included as info is not complete.

Comment: Here, i promise will re-eidt the problem code here once the cause is located to benifit future readers who might come into the same issue.

Comment: @j08691,as i fulfilled my promise to try my best to include SSCCE example along with the complete url here, would you remove the downvote of this question? (It took me another 1 hour as i'm indeed novice user with the stackoverflow code editor)

Answer (score 1):

Try Removing the code

```
<div class="carousel-nav-right-btn hidden-sm hidden-xs"></div>
```

and put your image not as a background but as a img src

```
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/1500/600/abstract/1" class="img-responsive">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption">

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a really similar issue. By me, it was some css code from an other plugin, what messed bootstrap carousel up.
This plugin had a css code like:

```
.left , .left .ticker-content, .left .ticker-title, .left .ticker {
    float: left;
}
```

I changed the selector, so it was not any more true to my carousel, and since that it's working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because of some float property. Disable floats one by one in css and find out which one causes the issue.

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Please update your bootstrap js files with new version.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was missing the **slide** class, the reason why this was missing was because Visual Studio (*or reSharper to be precise*) was telling me that "slide" was not a class so I removed it. And reSharper is right in the sense that there are no styles attached to that class by default and is therefore not being used...but it is used by bootstrap for a smooth transition which is why my slides were blank when it cycled between the carousel items because it wasn't able to apply the bootstrap logic to it.

So make sure you have this:

`<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">`

And not this:

`<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel" data-ride="carousel">`

Hope this helps someone! :)